# Telnet server & client code in c

Tags: c, network-programming

I am writing a telnet server and telnet client code but i am getting segmentation error.
I tried but i am not able to find the solution.Could anyone help me
i am working on ubuntu linux

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<sys/types.h>    
#include<netinet/in.h>    
#include<error.h>    
#include<strings.h>    
#include<unistd.h>    
#include<arpa/inet.h>    


#define ERROR -1    
#define MAX_CLIENTS 2    
#define MAX_DATA 1024


main(int argc, char **argv)    
{    
 struct sockaddr_in server;    
 struct sockaddr_in client;    
 int sock;    
 int new;    
 int sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);    
 int data_len;    
 char data[MAX_DATA];    


 if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == ERROR)    
 {    
  perror("server socket: ");    
  exit(-1);    
 }    

 server.sin_family = AF_INET;    
 server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));    
 server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
 bzero(&server.sin_zero, 8);    

 if((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)    
 {    
  perror("bind : ");    
  exit(-1);    
 }

 if((listen(sock, MAX_CLIENTS)) == ERROR)    
 {    
  perror("listen");    
  exit(-1);    
 }

 while(1) // Better signal handling required    
 {    
  if((new = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)    
  {    
   perror("accept");    
   exit(-1);    
  }    


  printf("New Client connected from port no %d and IP %s\n", ntohs(client.sin_port), net_ntoa(client.sin_addr));

  data_len = 1;            

  while(data_len)    
  {    
   data_len = recv(new, data, MAX_DATA, 0);    

   if(data_len)    
   {    
    send(new, data, data_len, 0);    
    data[data_len] = '\0';    
    printf("Sent mesg: %s", data);    
   }
  }

  printf("Client disconnected\n");

  close(new);       

 }

 close(sock);    
}
```

Comment: Can you format the code a little cleaner please? There's a button for it in the editor.

Comment: Also did you try running gdb/valgrind or some other debugger?

Comment: You really don't want to use int new; - COUGHCPLUSPLUSCOUGH

Comment: Use data_len > 0 in if condition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you nul-terminate `data` before printing it.

If `data_len` is `MAX_DATA`, then you will write the closing `'\0'` character off the end of the `data`  array.

Rather than trying to nul-terminate the data array, just use the `*` format character to tell `printf` how many characters to print:

```
printf("Sent mesg %.*s", data_len, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the program with an argument that will be the socket to listen on.
Your use of atoi

```
server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
```

is not checking whether  or not argv[1] exists.

Answer (score -1):

Why we are using `int new;` if you are using C++ compiler the new is keyword and operator to create an object of data as in your code it shows new as keyword with blue color.